# Accessing DialogFragment Views from another activity

Tags: android, view, android-dialogfragment

I have a class that extends `DialogFragment` that uses a layout inflater to display different views

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_pin_layout,null))
            .setTitle("Enter info")
            ...
    return builder.create();
}
```

The layout contains only an `EditText` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/infoEdit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I'm trying to auto-fill this `EditText` from my MainActivity

```
//When the user clicks on the button in the main activity, prompt MyDialog
ImageButton usr = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.usrImageButton);

 usr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MyDialog().show(getFragmentManager(),"fragment_info");

            //If userInfo exists, fill the DialogFragment's EditText
            if(userInfo!=null){
               EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.infoEdit);
               txt.setText(userInfo.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

When I run the app, clicking the button throws a NullPointerException caused by : `txt.setText(userInfo.toString());`.
By using the debugger, I found out that `(EditText)findViewById(R.id.infoEdit)` returns `null`, I guess that I'm not able to access the EditText View within my MainActivity by using `findViewById`. Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: try : EditText txt = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.infoEdit);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to pass the String to the DialogFragment and set it up there like so:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String text = args.getString("TEXT_TO_SET");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_pin_layout,null);
    EditText txt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.infoEdit);
    txt.setText(text);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Enter info")
            ...
    return builder.create();
}
```

and when creating the DialogFragment pass it the extra:

```
 DialogFragment fragment =  new MyDialog();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("TEXT_TO_SET",userInfo.toString());
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
 fragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"fragment_info");
```

Comment: The first, solution is not working, i'll try to pass the string to the DialogFragment.

Comment: @YounesMgharfaoui the first solution has been removed, it was not a good one. please give this a try. it is really how you should do it anyways

Comment: @YounesMgharfaoui no problem, happy coding. probably a good idea to check userInfo for empty string or null before passing and set a default value if nothing has been set